# Creating a location-based Augmented Reality POIs

Tags: geolocation, augmented-reality

I've been looking for a plugin to make a markerless, geolocated AR app.
The plot : The user is in the city and he wants to know the places etc
What I want to do is to be able to geolocate user in real world and display on a camera view the points of interests that he wants to see.
Do someone knows a way ?
Thank you mates;

Comment: I like to create a geo located  AR app with POI

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar, any luck finding something besides Vuforia or Wikitude?

Comment: @BrettStuart read his paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050916317574